# Retrieving all changed files for a branch using Azure DevOps git Rest Service Endpoints

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our Azure build pipeline requires knowing which solutions have changed on a branch so that it can just build the changed solutions. We hold each solution in a subdirectory off of the root.

We currently use the following PowerShell to retrieve the changes for a branch but if a later commit has been made then it only returns the changes in the last commit not for all commits.

$url="$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/commits?api-version=5.1"

So if our commits were:

Commit1 - Service1\codechanges.txt
Commit2 - Service2\codechanges.txt

The above would only return the changes in Commit2 whereas I want all changes for all commits.

Changing the url to be:

$url="$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/commits/$(Build.SourceVersion)?api-version=5.1"

No changes or endpoint appear to do what we require.

Comment: I would expect that a call to [`_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/commits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP) would be to get a list of commits, but that API doesn't provide the changes within a commit. For each commit of interest, a call would need to be made to [`_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/commits/{commitId}/changes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP) to get the changes within the commit.

Comment: The first call returns all commits which as you say I can then pass to the second call. What I really want is to be able to get the commits associated with a branch so that I can then retrieve the changes for those commits? Branches don't seem to be exposed by the REST api.

Comment: I have found the following link to retrieve a branch but I'm not sure what the serviceEndpointId should be set to; the call fails if it's not specified? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/source-providers/list-branches?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

Comment: It fails? The documentation says it is optional. Are you using the correct source provider name? For a git repo use "TFGit". For a TFVC repo use "TFVC".

Comment: My source code is in Azure DevOps so I assumed it would be Git. Changing it to TfsGit returns an empty collection for all branches or trying to find the current branch... $(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/sourceProviders/TfsGit/branches?api-version=7.0

Comment: Azure DevOps supports both git and TFVC. You can also use repos that are external to Azure DevOps. If you call the [list git repos API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP), does that return data?

Answer (score 0):

The solution we found was to use the following git command which gives the changed files between two branches, but only returns the changes found in the second branch:

```
git diff origin/master..origin/<branch name>
```